# Having trouble integrating BIRT with Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, birt

I am trying to integrate BIRT with Python Django. I created a form in Django that lets the user input parameters to a report. When the form is submitted, the view takes the parameters and creates a request and sends it to the BIRT Tomcat server. Now I am trying to render the response from the server. This is what I have in my view:

```
def birt_report(request, report_id, report_url=None, template='report_parameters.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportParametersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            report_params = form.save()
            form_id = report_params.id
            url = "http://<hostname>/BIRT-Viewer/frameset?__report=" + report_url + ".rptdesign"
            url += "&param_id=" + str(form_id)
            r = requests.get(url)
            return HttpResponse(content=str(r.content),status=200,content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8')
    else:
        form = ReportParametersForm()
        return render(request,template, {
            'form': form,
            'report_url': report_url,
            'report_id': report_id,
        })
```

Everything works up to the point where I try to render what the BIRT server sends back to me. I get the default BIRT web app toolbar. However, the report part of the page is blank. Here's what it looks like:

[image: BIRT-report]

The report gets generated properly in my Eclipse Report Designer preview. How do I get the report to render here? Thanks!

Edit:

I took a look at what was going on when the page was loading and I get this error in my Javascript console:

```
POST http://<hostname>/<Django_URL>/__sessionId=20130410_103510_658?__sessionId=20130410_103510_658 404 (NOT FOUND)
    prototype.js:656
Ajax.Request.Object.extend.request
    prototype.js:656
Ajax.Request.Object.extend.initialize
    prototype.js:631
(anonymous function)
    prototype.js:24
BirtCommunicationManager.connect
    BirtCommunicationManager.js:58
BirtEventDispatcher.sendEvent
    BirtEventDispatcher.js:179
BirtEventDispatcher.broadcastEvent
    BirtEventDispatcher.js:141
Object.extend.__init_pag
e    BirtNavigationBar.js:243
init
    <hostname>:1604
onload
    <hostname>:91
```

When I go to the report via the BIRT Viewer webapp that is included with BIRT, the Javascript file [b]prototype.js:656[/b], uses this URL:

```
http://<hostname>/BIRT-Viewer/frameset?__report=<report_name>.rptdesign&param_id=1&__sessionId=20130410_103510_658
```

instead of:

```
http://<hostname>/<Django_URL>/__sessionId=20130410_103510_658?__sessionId=20130410_103510_658
```

Comment: Do you got any exceptions ? while generating this report..

Comment: @SundarG I made an edit and added an error I saw.

Comment: This question is posted at and has an answer at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/29179-how-would-i-integrate-birt-with-python-django/